# How to use Burn Built-in Variables in Wix files .wxs

Tags: wix, burn

With the installation of my .msi I want to add a shortcut (.lnk) to the windows startup folder. (I do NOT want to add the .lnk to the registry in order to autostart my app! - *this would work already, but is not my intent!)*

Searching for a solution (btw: I know CustomAction are able to do the trick) I stumbled over [Burn's built-in variables](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/bundle_built_in_variables.html). 
As I understood it burn is used to chain multiple Wix installation packages.
**I wonder if/how I can use these burn built-in variables inside a .wxs file (shortcut/directory tag) also?**

By now I am using a single .wxs file

```
<Wix ..>
<Product ..>
...
```

Comment: Please clarify: Are you looking for a way to make variables visible to your bootstrapper also available in your chained packages?

Comment: Yes. I would like to have the (built-in) variables from my bootstrapper (burn) visible to my .wxs WiX Installer.

Comment: If my answer helped you I would be happy if you mark it as accepted answert. Thank you!

Comment: As soon as I can confirm your answer, i will! Thank you in advance. It might take me a few more days until I can give it a try and hope this is okay with you :)

Answer (score 3):

You can pass your variables to the packages via regular MSI-properties. Introduce a public property in your MSI-package and then set it via the *MsiProperty*-tag in the burn installer.

In the WXS-file of the MSI-packages:

```
<Property Id="MYPROP" Value="DefaultValue"/>
```

In the WXS-file of the bootstrapper you can set the variable:

```
<MsiPackage SourceFile="MyFile.msi">
  <MsiProperty Name="MYPROP" Value="[StartupFolder]" />
</MsiPackage>
```

You can use this variable inside your MSI-package via the *[MYPROP]* in many tags.

Note that public properties must be made up of only uppercase letters.

Comment: I am not able to refer from <directory> or <shortcut> tag (inside the MSI-package) to the value of the <poperty> tag (inside the same MSI-package). So the build of the MSI-wxs file already failes. "Unresolved reference to symbol 'Directory:MYPROP'"

So from what I understand, I can use these <property> tag only for certain Wix-tags also supporting a property attribute, right? And that in turn means I still need some a custom action to define the location of my shortcut at the end?